# What is the name of this connector and how can I find an adapter?

Tags: connector, identification, cables, adapter

I have the following connector (see image below) with contains 5 metallic pins (4 pins are used for a 4-probe IV measurement + 1 ground). Its diameter is 6.65 mm.
What is the name of this connector?

[image: photo of connector]

I would like to connect it to a Keithley 2400 series, possibly using the 4 different triax connectors.

Do you know of any adapter I should use?
Thank you

EDIT:
This cable is for a 4 pin probing system with ground. We use it to test microelectronic devices. It is basically the connection to 4 metallic pins.

On the one side, the cable looks different, as it has a different head connector:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it off a piece of marine equipment?

Comment: Unless it is top-secret, please tell us where the connector came from or what it is used for, etc. It looks a little bit like a Higo connector (used for E-bikes and such). But it is awfully hard to say. There are a lot of round connectors with pins in them... Maybe a few more pictures, also. Like a side view.

Comment: @BrianDrummond It is not marine. It is a connector for a microelectronic testing component. See the EDIT

Comment: Amphenol have some version of pretty much every kind of circular connector ever made, they have hundreds of connectors similar to these. I'd start by looking there.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a non standard variant of Mini-DIN

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-DIN_connector#Non-standard_connectors